# Grub2 zfs how to boot

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, dual-boot

Can someone point me which are the commands from grub to boot Ubuntu zfs 19?
Making an `update-grub` I just have the windows boot and noot the ubuntu anymore.

Comment: Can you explain what you did to get to this point. Did you install Ubuntu 19.x fresh on your machine?  What do you mean you just have windows boot.  Are you saying the menu item to boot Ubuntu is missing?

Comment: Philip:that's correct.ubuntu is missing.

Comment: Menu items are all created when you run `update-grub`. How are you managing to run this if you can't boot?  Are you running this in a chroot environment?

Comment: After the installing i put the windows 10 disk back then i managed an update-grub and the ubuntu item was deleted,but the grub console is ok i just need some tips

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean. You say you managed an update-grub grub after putting back the windows 10 disk....  update-grub should be run from inside Ubuntu. It uses scripts in /etc/ to detect and configure the menu items.  You can use a chroot into your grub install to do this... Eg https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526009/20140 this was for mint but the same works with ubintu

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding,i tried to install Ubuntu several times,last time i took off two disk windows one and the Freebsd.then finished the installation i gave the update-grub command just to rekognizle the windows disk,but unfortunatly the ubuntu item were deleted.I make clearl one more time it's an zfs installation othere wise i will not have problems